# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Tags: javascript

My code appears to be correct, but when I run it I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
This is my code below:

```
function Classes(subject, class, scheduled) {
  this.subject = subject;
  this.class = class;
  this.scheduled = scheduled;
  this.checkAvailablility = function() {
return this.class - this.scheduled;
}; 
}

var CourseHistory = new Classes('history', 30, 23);
var CourseScience = new Classes('science', 45, 38);
```

Comment: class is a [reserved word](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp). The comma after class is not expected.

Answer (score 6):

`class` is a reserved keyword in Javascript. You can't use it as a variable name.

When the function definition is parsed, the compiler expects a class name to be followed after `class` keyword, when it is not present it throws a syntax error as it does not conform to the syntax.